# errors caused due to migrating from ifort to gfortran

Tags: fortran, mpi, gfortran

I had a code that was running perfectly on a machine uses ifort and mpif90 
I tried to compile it again on another machine where gfortran is installed instead of ifort 
I got errors like those

```
open(unit=10,name=oldfile,access='APPEND',                        
               1
```

Error: Syntax error in OPEN statement at (1)
main.f

Does anyone knows how can i solve this?

Comment: actually that is the error that appeared however the original code is 
open(unit=10,name=oldfile,access='APPEND',
     +       status='unknown')

Answer (score 3):

access='append' is not standard fortran and gfortran does not support it. The ifort manual says what the exact meaning is. The equivalent standard conforming code would be access='sequential', position='append'.

Comment: A link to ifort's documentation of the extension is: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/511248

Comment: @francescalus: seems my guess was correct then, yay.

Answer (score 1):

I think the immediate error reported is actually caused by the

```
name=oldfile
```

that is an extension. Standard Fortran is

```
file=oldfile
```

The incorrect value for access will be checked later.

The overview of the possible specifiers in the openstatements for Intel Fortran is at https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/511247 The green ones are non-standard and will likely not work in other compilers (e.g., gfortran).